# How does Picard recognize Seven of Nine?

Tags: star-trek, jean-luc-picard, star-trek-picard, seven-of-nine

In season 1, episode 4 of *Star Trek: Picard*, Seven of Nine shows up, and Picard immediately recognizes her, by name. How? As far as I know, they've never met before, or at least we certainly haven't seen them together before. Is she famous, or is it an ex-Borg connection, or what?

(If it's just something we'll have to wait and find out in future episodes, that's an answer, too; what I'm really wondering is if there has actually been mention of their relationship before and I just missed it, or something like that.)

Comment: I'd imagine that Picard voraciously consumes any Starfleet Intel with the keyword "Borg" attached

Comment: @Valorum If he wasn't immediately dragged in to assist a security review as soon as Starfleet command became aware of her; "How can we be sure we can really trust her, and she can't be suborned?"

Comment: Also, Seven was probably instantly famous when Voyager came back to the Federation

Comment: @DavidW from what I can tell with my limited google-fu... he resigned as admiral in 2385 and voyager didn't return home until 2394... however, voyager took 23 years or something... so that's plenty of time for Picard at even at captain rank to know what was going on or something?

Comment: @JonClements 2394 is Voyager's "original" return date, before the meddling by Admiral Janeway in the finale, *Endgame*. The ship actually returned in 2378.

Comment: @T.J.L. ahh... so there's a window of 7 years where Picard was Admiral and the Voyager crew was home... so ample opportunity for Picard to have met or at least recognised Seven then I guess?

Comment: There's https://uk.ign.com/articles/picard-seven-of-nine-blames-picard-jeri-ryan but I stopped reading it as it has spoilers. Maybe just wait till the next episode.

Comment: @JonClements, they returned home before Picard made Admiral. Janeway, as an admiral, appeared in *Star Trek Nemesis* when Picard was still captain of the 1701-E.

Comment: People should realize by now that, like *Discovery* before it, *Picard* is interested in making money, not continuity.

Comment: When Voyager returned home this was big news and the crew was listed and all these reports came out and people probably were interested in the ex-Borg on Voyager.

Comment: @BenjaminErickson: but that was 20 effing years ago. Do *you* remember what was in the news 20 years ago?

Comment: @Martha No, but Picard is also ex-Borg. I would be far more likely to remember news-about-a-person-with-a-similar-rare-experience-as-me than one with no commonality. (Also... ISS Expedition 1 began a few days before my birthday in 2020. I remember it because it was near my birthday and I find space exploration interesting. I would not expect anybody else to remember without some good self-related reason.)

Comment: https://www.cbr.com/star-trek-picard-seven-of-nine-how-recognized/ - By reputation

Answer (score 28):

Why *wouldn't* Picard recognize Seven of Nine?

Looking just at the canon of *Star Trek: Voyager*, we know that the Voyager crew is the only ship to make it to the Delta Quadrant and back. In addition, they had a rather extensive experience with the Borg in the process.

The very fact that they went out to the Delta Quadrant and back means that as soon as they arrived back in Federation territory, they're instantly famous. They've traveled further than anyone else in the Federation. Think of, say, Neil Armstrong - anyone who even took a passing interest in space would, at the time that the crew of Apollo 11 returned to Earth, recognize them.

Picard is a Starfleet Captain, which means he would have gotten briefings and had access to information about Voyager that extend further than your average citizen would have gotten.

In addition, Picard and the Voyager crew - *especially* Seven of Nine - have had dealings with the Borg. It would make sense that Picard would keep up on any news about the Borg, especially someone who, *like him*, was assimilated and then *removed from the Collective*.

Even if you assume they've never met in person before, it's safe to assume that Picard would have seen news and briefings and other information about the entire Voyager crew and especially Seven of Nine.

Comment: And the Borg implant above her eye would be a clue. :-)

Comment: But Voyager's return was more than 20 years ago by this point. Any fame would've worn off long ago, and everyone *is* older and *looks* older.

Comment: Janeway was noted as an Admiral in Star Trek Nemesis; though I do not remember if that scene persists in all edits of the film.  I would imagine that Picard and Janeway would also have had conversations about Voyager and Senior Officers (including Seven).

Comment: In episode 5, Captain Rios' reaction is more in line with what I'd expect for someone who was a celebrity briefly 20+ years ago: he knows she's famous and ex-Borg, but can't come up with her name to save his life. Even if Picard was more closely acquainted/involved with Voyager's return, remembering Seven of Nine's full name, in stressful circumstances where she's the last person he expects to encounter, is hard to believe.

Comment: I just watched "Inside Man" (from the last season) and during that time Voyager was in contact with Earth on a regular basis.  Part of dialogue suggested that everyone on Earth was aware of Seven's heritage and that she was famous for being a Borg that escaped the collective.

Answer (score 5):

In Voyager *Infinite Regress*, we see that Seven develops a form of dissociative identity disorder, with multiple personalities surfacing. We later learn that these are all people she's assimilated, which is noteworthy because one of them is a woman from the USS *Melbourne* from the **Battle of Wolf 359**. (How Seven survived the battle deserves its own question on this site.)

The point being that *Seven wasn't entirely unknown to Locutus*. And as Mithical's answer states, when Seven arrived, she surely would have garnered some fame, and would have stood out doubly to Picard as he may have recognized her by that point already. (In the sense that we might recognize an old schoolmate or something, not that he knew her, just that he saw her around).

TL;DR: Seven somehow was at and survived Wolf 359, which is probably enough distinction on its own for Picard/Locutus to remember her.

Comment: Great answer! I doubt however that picard/locutus knows every face of every involved drone well enough to recognize them immediately years later without any implants

Comment: Just to add... it has never been canonically stated that 7of9 was at Wolf359. The people she assimilated were but they were somehow transported back to the delta quadrant after or before the Borg cube was destroyed at Wolf359, both of which has also not been canonically stated in any of the TV shows.